Conductor and ramification in the Kronecker-Weber theorem
Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be an abelian number field. By the Kronecker-Weber theorem, there exists a number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ ($\zeta_m$ is a primitive $m$th root of unity). The smallest $m$ with this property is the called the conductor of $K$. Denote it by $c$.
Does anyone knows a source for the proof of the following theorem:
$\phantom{aaa}$If $p$ is a prime number, then $p$ ramifies in $K$ iff $p|c$?
As an alternative to a reference, maybe those statements are not too hard to prove and some could give me some ideas on where to start. Thanks!

Everything follows by studying ramification in cyclotomic fields closely.
Suppose that $p$ ramifies in $K$. Then we need to have $p \mid c$, because ramification in cyclotomic fields over $\Bbb Q$ is well-understood, in particular $\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$ is unramified for $p \nmid m$.
Suppose that $p$ is unramified in $K$ and $K\subseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})$ with $p \nmid m$. Then $K$ is contained in the inertia field of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})$ corresponding to $p$, because that's the largest field of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})$ in which $p$ is unramified. So it all boils down to computing inertia fields of cyclotomic fields.
I claim that the inertia field of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})$ is $\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$. As already mentioned, $p$ is unramified in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$. To show that there's no larger subfield in which $p$ is unramified it suffices to show that primes above $p$ are totally ramified in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})/\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$. It's well-known that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^k})/ \Bbb Q$ is totally ramified and $\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)/\Bbb Q$ is unramified (everything at $p$). This implies that $$[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km}):\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)]\geq e(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})|\Bbb Q(\zeta_m))=e(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})|\Bbb Q(\zeta_m))e(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{m})|\Bbb Q)\\=e(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})|\Bbb Q)\geq e(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^k})|\Bbb Q)=[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^k}):\Bbb Q]$$
But $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km}):\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)]\leq [\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^k}):\Bbb Q]$, because $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})=\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^k})\cdot\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$. Thus all inequalities above are actually equalities, in particular $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km}):\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)]= e(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})|\Bbb Q(\zeta_m))$, i.e. $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^km})/\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$ is totally ramified as claimed.
Thus $K\subseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$. Thus $p$ can't divide the smallest $n$ such that $K\subseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$.
